# Randomise dates in MySql sample data

Tags: mysql, random

I've created a sample data set in a MySql database that I need to use to test generating some reports with. For one particular table I've got 100k records that were all created within a few hours of each other. Because of the way the sample data was generated I couldn't set the datetime columns on the 100k records to the desired values.

How can I use an SQL statement to randomise the datetime columns on the 100k records so instead of being within a few hours of each other they are spread across a month? As an example I'd like to spread the records evenly across the interval 1st Oct 2012 to 31st Oct 2012.

Comment: Elaborate as *randomly* and *evenly* don't go together. Also, I assume performance is not a concern since you are seeding the sample data?

Comment: I just need the dates to be spread throughout a 30 day period in a pseudo-random manner. Performance isn't a concern as it will be a once off task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `RAND()` function.  Following [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand), to obtain a random integer `R` in the range `i <= R < j`, use the expression `FLOOR(i + RAND() * (j – i))`.  So for every row in your sample table, you'd need to run the following query:

```
SET @year = '2012';
SET @month = '10';
SET @day = FLOOR(1 + RAND() * (31 - 1));
SET @hour = FLOOR(0 + RAND() * (23 - 0));
SET @minute = FLOOR(0 + RAND() * (59 - 0));
SET @second = FLOOR(0 + RAND() * (59 - 0));

SET @date = CONCAT(@year,'-',@month,'-',@day,'-',@hour,'-',@minute,'-',@second);

UPDATE `sample_tbl`
   SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE(@date,'%Y-%c-%e-%k-%i-%s');
```

Comment: That got me close, thx. Of course running the query that way will result in all the dates being the same. This is what I used: UPDATE `userauthorisation` SET `inserted` = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2012-10-',FLOOR(1 + RAND() * (31 - 1)),'-',FLOOR(0 + RAND() * (23 - 0)),'-',FLOOR(0 + RAND() * (59 - 0)),'-',FLOOR(0 + RAND() * (59 - 0))),'%Y-%c-%e-%k-%i-%s');

Answer (score 1):

Intriguing question. I have needed something similar before. The following is a proof of concept.

```
SET @start_timestamp = 1349049600;
SET @end_timestamp = 1351641600;
SET @offset = @end_timestamp - @start_timestamp;

SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(@start_timestamp + FLOOR(RAND() * @offset));
```

#### A Fail Note

Although [flow control statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flow-control-statements.html) exist in MySQL (`WHILE`, `LOOP`, etc), they are only available within stored programs.

I tried to `JOIN` an existing table against the `SELECT` directly. However, the timestamp was always the same value.

I tried to create a `dates` table and seed it using `BENCHMARK(100000, INSERT ...)`. But it only accepts scalar expressions for the second argument.

In the end, you could overcome all of the above by writing a stored program. However, that seemed overkill as I believe in your case adapting this POC into your original script makes the most sense.